# Python file not importing

Tags: python

I import the python file, but it does not import the file even though it exists and I get the error ''modulenotfounderror: No module named''. There was no problem before, now it started. Why could it be?

Comment: Add your code to the post.

Comment: Show how your files are structured and how you're importing. Without this there's no way we can help, it can be anything.

Comment: How can we know without seeing your code that has led to this error?

Comment: from offsets.run import * 

from offsets.run import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'offsets'

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is it, but it's likely that the filename has been changed or is in a different directory
If not, try putting the file in a folder and importing it:

```py
script.py
  modules/
      __init__.py 
       module1.py
```

and in your script.py file try to put:

```py
from modules import module1
```

If not, I suggest putting in your question how your directories and program are organized. It is worth mentioning that the import is based on the main script where the program runs, all imports must be based on the location of the main script.

Example:

```py
script.py
  modules/
       __init__.py 
       module1.py
       modules2/
          __init__.py 
          module2.py
```

and in your script.py file try to put:

```py
from modules import module1
from modules.modules2 import module2
```

in your module1.py file try to put:

```py
from modules.modules2 import module2
```

don't import the file like that:

```py
from modules2 import module2
```